# How do I get PySpark/spark to run on both python2 and 3 on my computer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6

I have Spark/Pyspark for python 2.7.

I also have python 3.6 on my computer.

How can I get it spark/pyspark to automatically run on python3.6?

Spark/pyspark will only currently run on 2.7 for my computer

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to set Python interpreter for executors.
- `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environment variable to set Python interpret for the driver.

`PYSPARK_PYTHON` should be set on each worker node. It is best to use `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`, i.e

```
$ cat $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PYSPARK_PYTHON={which python3.6}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be a little more specific as to where you input this code?

I.e. is it in the python file you import pyspark? somewhere else?